# Using one fragment more times with different listeners [Android]

Tags: java, android, android-activity, listener, fragment

I have an android app with 4 main tabs. Each tab contains different fragment. I also have ListFragment which I want to show in each of those fragments but with other OnItemClickListener (because it has same layout and data but behaves differently on click).

Is the right way?

```
public class MyListFragment extends ListFragment {
    ...
    public void setOnItemClickListener(OnItemClickListener listener) {
        getList().setOnItemClickListener(listener);
    }
}
```

and in parent fragments do this:

```
public class FirstParentFragment extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_beach_list, container, false);

        FragmentManager fm = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
        MyListFragment fragment = (MyListFragment )fm.findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_list_first);
        OnItemClickListener listener = new OnItemClickListener(...bla bla...);
        fragment.setOnItemClickListener(listener);

        return view;
    }
}
```

Thanks for answers :)

Comment: Have you managed to make this work yet?

Comment: Hello Schaem. Code I wrote above cannot work, specificly in FirstParentFragment's onCreateView - calling fragment.setOnItemClickListener(listener) should end with null exception or something. That is because of MyListFragment's listView is not inicialised at that time.

Comment: Only soulution that comes to my mind is to call some method of MyListFragment's parent activity after initialising listView (possibly in CreateView or ViewCreated). And inside this activity method you just tell to FirstParentFragment that it's MyListFragment has its list initialised and its list's OnItemClickListener can be set. Hope it is understandable... otherwise I can wrote some sample code for you if needed :)

Comment: I found a way to make it work, might not be the best way, but it works, thanks anyway ;)